# Dlib facial landmark starting index

Tags: dlib

I'm using dlib to get facial landmark points , my question is about the

indexing , the reference figure of 68 landmark is starts from (1) ,

is dlib code [Dlib facial landmarks](https://github.com/davisking/dlib/blob/master/examples/face_landmark_detection_ex.cpp) starts from (0) ? so if I wanted to output left eye landmarks

using dlib should I start from **(37)** as the reference figure or **(38)** ?

[image]

Comment: That is because C++ starts indexing from `0`, not `1`. So in an array, the first element's index is `[0]`. In your case, `landmarks[37]` corresponds to the `38th` actual point.

Answer (score 1):

I have created an image and printed out the index numbers as they are with dlib and python here: http://cvdrone.de/dlib-facial-landmark-detection.html

Answer (score -1):

left eye landmarks are 36 to 41 in dlib
some images that start from 1 is not correct dlib landmarks are from 0 to 67  which makes 68 points